# UI on debian VPS on Ionos

Tags: user-interface, debian, vps, vnc, vnc-server

I just get a VPS on Ionos, in which debian is running.
I use it to run selenium script with python but I would like to control what the script is doing when I get errors. So I would to install an UI and control it with vnc viewer.
Anyone knows if it possible ?
If yes, which ui I can install on my VPS ? and which vncserver package is the the best ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "apt install XFCE4" Desktop, then you have a UI.

You can access this desktop from Windows machines when you "apt install XRDP" and login via Remote Desktop.

Dont forget to open RDP Port 3389 in the firewall.